Can I manipulate Op object in Jena SPARQL?
I uesed Algebra.exec(opgraph,Dataset) and converted an OpGraph object to an OpTable object, I want to replace OpGraph in my original Query op with the OpTalbe object, so What should I do?
I try to use Opvisitor to find OpGraph target, but can't replace it.

Changing the algebra is done with org.apache.jena.sparql.algebraTransform apllied using org.apache.jena.sparql.algebra.Transformer.

If I want to replace a part of an Op, using an OpTable, what should I do? Could you give me more advice?

You will need to use a Transform (best to subclass TransformCopy) and apply it with Transformer. This will walk the Op structure to find th epart you want to change. There are many examples in the Jena codebase.

Thanks for your help, I made it. But if I want to delete an Op(like a Opflter) from my queryOp, what should I do?

Find the place in the algebra tree which contains the OpFilter and transform it to a fres element that does not contain the OpFilter.
